# Whenever trying to get message from inbox field set fails

Tags: android, database, inbox

i am trying to view my inbox grouped by their sender numbers. For this first i find all the message from the inbox to their number and then when they click on a particular item he will see the conversation between them. But getting an error.

here is my code:

```
public void initialize() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),
                null, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        int indexBody = cursor.getColumnIndex(SmsReceiver.BODY);
        int indexAddr = cursor.getColumnIndex(SmsReceiver.ADDRESS);
        int i = 0, flag = 0;



        if (indexBody < 0 || !cursor.moveToFirst())
            return;

        smsList.clear();

        do {
            // int cursorPostion = cursor.getPosition();

            String address;
            String msgStr = cursor.getString(indexBody);
            String senderNumber = cursor.getString(indexAddr);
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));

            if (name != null) {
                address = name;
            } else {
                address = senderNumber;
            }
            flag = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < addressUniqueness.length; j++) {
                if (addressUniqueness[j].contentEquals(address)) {
                    flag = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (flag == 1) {
                addressUniqueness[i] = address;
                i++;

                String str = "Sender: " + address + "\n";
                smsList.add(str);

            }

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        // cursor.moveToNext();
        // }

        ListView smsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SMSList);
        smsListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smsList));
        smsListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
```

getting this error:

```
01-08 22:09:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(650): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 22:09:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(650): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.InboxList}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
01-08 22:09:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-08 22:09:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-08 22:09:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-08 22:09:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-08 22:09:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-08 22:09:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-08 22:09:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-08 22:09:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 22:09:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-08 22:09:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-08 22:09:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-08 22:09:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-08 22:09:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(650): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
01-08 22:09:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.database.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method)
01-08 22:09:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:329)
01-08 22:09:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:49)
01-08 22:09:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:135)
01-08 22:09:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at com.InboxList.initialize(InboxList.java:153)
01-08 22:09:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at com.InboxList.onCreate(InboxList.java:74)
01-08 22:09:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-08 22:09:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-08 22:09:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: What is line number 153 in com.InboxList.initialize() method and line 74 in com.InboxList.onCreate() method ??

Comment: i have call this initialize method on the inboxlist create activity